# Adding a new column in pandas which is the total sum of the values of another column

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, pandas-groupby

So I'm using pandas and trying to add a new column in called 'Total' where its the sum of all the numbers of vehicles for that year.

From this:

```
    type            year     number

Private cars        2005    401638
Motorcycles         2005    138588
Off peak cars       2005    12947
Motorcycles         2005    846
```

To something like this:

```
 type            year       number       Total

Private cars        2005    401638      554019
Motorcycles         2005    138588
Off peak cars       2005    12947
Motorcycles         2005    846
```

Comment: Your output makes no sense. Why is the Total in the Private cars row?

Answer (score 2):

Using `GroupBy` + `transform` with `sum`:

```
df['Year_Total'] = df.groupby('year')['number'].transform('sum')
```

Note this will give you the yearly total for each row. If you wish to "blank out" totals for certain rows, you should specify precisely the logic for this.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) and then if necessary replace duplicated values:

```
df['Total'] = df.groupby('year')['number'].transform('sum')
print (df)
            type  year  number  Total
0   Private cars  2005       1      3
1    Motorcycles  2005       2      3
2  Off peak cars  2006       5     20
3    Motorcycles  2006       7     20
4   Motorcycles1  2006       8     20

df.loc[df['year'].duplicated(), 'Total'] = np.nan
print (df)
            type  year  number  Total
0   Private cars  2005       1    3.0
1    Motorcycles  2005       2    NaN
2  Off peak cars  2006       5   20.0
3    Motorcycles  2006       7    NaN
4   Motorcycles1  2006       8    NaN
```

Replacing to empty values is possible, but not recommended, because get mixed values numeric with strings and some function should failed:

```
df.loc[df['year'].duplicated(), 'Total'] = ''
print (df)
            type  year  number Total
0   Private cars  2005       1     3
1    Motorcycles  2005       2      
2  Off peak cars  2006       5    20
3    Motorcycles  2006       7      
4   Motorcycles1  2006       8
```

Answer (score 0):

This gives a similar dataframe:

```
total = df['numer'].sum()
df['Total'] = np.ones_line(df['number'].values) * total
```

Comment: doing this over two lines is unnecessary - `df['Total'] = df['numer'].sum()` should have the same effect